# bash checking all the elements in a list are within a range

Tags: bash

```
LessThanThirty=1
GreaterThanTwenty=1

while read line 
do
    LessThanThirty=$(echo "$line <= 30.0" | bc)
    GreaterThanTwenty=$(echo "$line >= 20.0" | bc)
done < <(grep -A 26 "some text" someFile.txt | awk '/More Text/ { gsub(/M/, " "); print $4 }'     | uniq )

echo $LessThanThirty
echo $GreaterThanTwenty
```

I have a whole list of numbers and want to test that they are all within the range of 20 - 30. if any of them are greater than 30 then LessThanThirty should remain false. As it stands, my Echo's at the end are only reporting the status of the checks on the last element in the list. I need a way for my variables to be set false if ANY of the numbers in the list are within the range.

Comment: Sorry, that was a tad vague. Edited Question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the comparisons in `awk`:

```
read GreaterThanTwenty LessThanThirty < <(
 grep -A 26 "some text" someFile.txt | \
 awk '/More Text/ { gsub(/M/, " "); print $4 }' | \
 awk 'BEGIN { g20=l30=1 }
      $0 < 20.0 { g20=0 }
      $0 > 30.0 { l30=0 }
      END { print g20, l30 }'
 )
```

You can probably eliminate the call to `uniq` and merge the two `awk` scripts into one fairly easily by using an `awk` array to eliminate duplicates, but this demonstrates the idea.

This works by setting two `awk` variables, `g20` and `l30` initially to 1. If an input line is ever less than 20, we set `g20` to 0 (i.e., not all inputs are greater than 20). Likewise, we set `l30` to 0 if any input is ever greater than 30. After consuming all the input, we print the values of `g20` and `l30`. This becomes the output of the process substitution, which is read into the two `bash` variables using the `read` command.

(I've removed the call to `uniq`, since it requires its input to be sorted anyway, and you don't seem to be interested in counts, just the existence of values outside of the range. It will probably take more time to sort and remove duplicates than it will to just run them all through `awk` to do the range check. This would make it easier to merge the two `awk` programs, but for simplicity I'll leave them be.)

Comment: Can you explain this step by step? I'm still not very familiar with bash in general, and discovered awk only yesterday.

Comment: I edited my answer after rereading your question; I'll add an explanation.

Comment: Pretty sure this does exactly what I need! Now I need to clean up the input I send in. As it is, every line that has "More Text" is parsed, but what I really need is to check only the ones at a certain point in the file...

Comment: The code in the answer works as expected, but ca you explain whats happening here? 

    if [[ $GreaterThanTwenty==1 && $LessThanThirty==1 ]]

The Within limits is triggered, even though further echoes show that LessThanTwenty is infact 0 at this time.
    then
        echo "within limits"
    else
        echo "Outside limits"
    fi

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just OR together your variables:

```
LessThanThirty=0
GreaterThanTwenty=0

while read line 
do
    LessThanThirty=$(echo "$line <= 30.0 || $LessThanThirty" | bc)
    GreaterThanTwenty=$(echo "$line >= 20.0 || $GreaterThanTwenty" | bc)
done < <(grep -A 26 "some text" someFile.txt | awk '/More Text/ { gsub(/M/, " "); print $4 }'     | uniq )

echo $LessThanThirty
echo $GreaterThanTwenty
```

But now the variables have to start as false.